# Object contains another object. How to show it in TableView?

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I'm using `SceneBuilder` to build a GUI. Now i do have a problem. If i want to show an single object in a `TableView` everything works fine but if i am using another constructor which contains another object, the second object just doesn't appear in the `TableView`.

code:

```
public class MainController implements Initializable {

@FXML
TableView<Table> tableID;
@FXML
TableColumn<Table, Integer> iID;
@FXML
TableColumn<Table, String> iName;
@FXML
TableColumn<Table, String> iDate;
@FXML
TableColumn<Table, Integer> iPrice;
@FXML
TableColumn<Table1, String> surname;
@FXML
TableColumn<Table1, String> name;

Table1 t1 = new Table1("just", "testing");

final ObservableList<Table> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
        new Table(t1, 12, "Name 1", "01/01/20012", 50),
        new Table(t1, 1, "Name 1", "01/01/20012", 50),
        new Table(t1, 3, "Name 1", "01/01/20012", 50));

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

    iID.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Table, Integer>("rID"));   
    iName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Table, String>("rName"));    
    iDate.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Table, String>("rDate"));    
    iPrice.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Table, Integer>("rPrice"));
    surname.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Table1, String>("surname"));   
    name.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Table1, String>("name")); 

    tableID.setItems(data);

}
```

Table1 class;

```
private String surname;
private String name;

public Table1(){

}

public Table1(String surname, String name){
    this.name = name;
    this.surname = surname;
}

public String getVorname() {
    return surname;
}

public void setVorname(String surname) {
    this.surname = surname;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

Table class;

```
    private final SimpleIntegerProperty rID;
private final SimpleStringProperty rName;;
private final SimpleStringProperty rDate;
private final SimpleIntegerProperty rPrice;

Table1 t1 = new Table1("just", "testing");

public Table(Table1 t1, int sID, String sName, String sDate, Integer sPrice) {
    this.rID = new SimpleIntegerProperty(sID);
    this.rName = new SimpleStringProperty(sName);
    this.rDate = new SimpleStringProperty(sDate);
    this.rPrice = new SimpleIntegerProperty(sPrice);
}

public Integer getRID() {
    return rID.get();
}

public void setRID(Integer v) {
    rID.set(v);
}

public String getRName() {
    return rName.get();

}

public void setRName(String v) {
    rName.set(v);

}
public String getRData(){
    return rDate.get();

}

public void setRDate(String v){
    rDate.set(v);

}
public Integer getRPrice(){
    return rPrice.get();

}

public void setRNPrice(Integer v){
    rPrice.set(v);

}
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for Cell Customization. 
This link may help you: http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-8-tableview-cell-renderer/

**EDIT:**

This code will give you some errors. For example, you are setting that the `TableView<>` will contain objects of type `Table`, so you cannot set a `TableColumn<>` of type `Table1`.

As well, you first need to initialize the `TableView` and the `TableColumn`s.

The solution that I found: you can write `getters` in the `Table` class that return the respectively `name` and `surname` from the `Table1`.

Here is the code that you need (just the changes):

> At class `MainController`:

```
    TableColumn<Table, String> surname; //Instead of Table1
    TableColumn<Table, String> name;    //Instead of Table1
    //DONT FORGET TO INITIALIZE THE TableColumns and TableView
```

> At class `Table`:

```
private Table1 t1;

public Table(Table1 t1, int sID, String sName, String sDate, Integer sPrice) {
    this.rID = new SimpleIntegerProperty(sID);
    this.rName = new SimpleStringProperty(sName);
    this.rDate = new SimpleStringProperty(sDate);
    this.rPrice = new SimpleIntegerProperty(sPrice);
    this.t1 = t1;
}
//Add this
public String getName(){
    return t1.getName();
}
//Add this
public String getSurname(){
    return t1.getVorname();
    //Bist Du Deutscher? :D
}
```

Comment: hmm... Thanks for your answer but i can't get the needed information out of this link. My problem is that the second object doesn't appear at all in the tableview...

Comment: Thank you very much! I just simply forgot to complete the constructor with "this.t1 = t1;" Ja ich bin deutscher, danke Dir vielmals! Die Lösung ist oft simpler, als man denkt...

Comment: Hey I was looking to my answers and I found that you didn't marked it as correct. Since it helped you solve your problem, could you help me by checking it as correct? With that I can better help you and other programmers here. Thank you very much!